How do I resolve 100% accuracy on random forest for my fraud detection model?
Took this dataset from kaggle to design a fraud detection ML model for learning/practice. did the data cleaning and combined the severals datasets into a final_df. added bunch of derived features during preprocessing, did required encoding, feature scaling, dropped few columns etc. prepared the data for train/test split and used the RandomForestClassifier to perform the fit(X_train, y_train) and prediction y_pred followed by running the classification report and accuracy_score and confusion matrix.
Problem is I am getting for precision, recall, f1_score all as 1.00 and support 200 for accuracy, macro avg and weighted avg. and confusion matrix as 200. i am not sure how do i go about resolving this overfitting since the dataset does contain fraudulent transactions?
Also, when running the print(roc_auc_score(y_test, rf_model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1])) its gives
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

I am not sure why this is and how do i go about resolving.
here is the code. I have not included data cleaning and combining/merging tables part but everything from data preprocessing to creating the RF model. here is the final_df that I am be working with.
final_df.to_csv('FraudDetection_df.csv', index=False)
    final_df['LastLogin'] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['LastLogin'], errors='coerce')

# Data Preprocessing
# applying label encoding
    le = LabelEncoder()
    final_df['CustomerID'] = le.fit_transform(final_df['CustomerID'])
    final_df['MerchantID'] = le.fit_transform(final_df['MerchantID'])`

# calculating mean fraud rate per merchant
    merchant_fraud_rate = final_df.groupby('MerchantName')['FraudIndicator'].mean()
# Map the fraud rate back to the original dataframe
    final_df['MerchantRisk'] = final_df['MerchantName'].map(merchant_fraud_rate)

# calculating mean fraud rate per customer
    customer_fraud_rate = final_df.groupby('Name')['FraudIndicator'].mean()
# Map the fraud rate back to the original dataframe
    final_df['CustomerRisk'] = final_df['Name'].map(customer_fraud_rate)

# Applying StandardScaler
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    final_df[['TransactionAmount', 'AccountBalance']] = scaler.fit_transform(final_df[['TransactionAmount', 'AccountBalance']])

# Average transaction amount per customer
    avg_transaction_amount = final_df.groupby('CustomerID')['TransactionAmount'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_transaction_amount.rename(columns={'TransactionAmount': 'AvgTransactionAmount'}, inplace=True)
# Merge with original dataframe
    final_df = pd.merge(final_df, avg_transaction_amount, on='CustomerID', how='left')
# Average transaction amount per merchant
    avg_transaction_amount_merchant = final_df.groupby('MerchantID')['TransactionAmount'].mean().reset_index()
    avg_transaction_amount_merchant.rename(columns={'TransactionAmount': 'AvgTransactionAmount_Merchant'}, inplace=True)
    final_df = pd.merge(final_df, avg_transaction_amount_merchant, on='MerchantID', how='left')

# Calculate variance in transaction amounts per customer
    transaction_variance = final_df.groupby('CustomerID')['TransactionAmount'].var().reset_index()
    transaction_variance.rename(columns={'TransactionAmount': 'TransactionVariance'}, inplace=True)
# Merge with original dataframe
    final_df = pd.merge(final_df, transaction_variance, on='CustomerID', how='left')

# Creating a flag for single-transaction customers
    final_df['SingleTransactionFlag'] = final_df['TransactionVariance'].isna().astype(int)
# Replace NaN values in the variance column with 0
    final_df['TransactionVariance'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

    pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)

    final_df['AvgTransactionAmount_Customer'] = final_df.groupby('CustomerID')['TransactionAmount'].transform('mean')
    final_df['AvgTransactionAmount_Merchant'] = final_df.groupby('MerchantName')['TransactionAmount'].transform('mean')

    final_df['SpendingTrend'] = final_df.groupby('CustomerID')['TransactionAmount'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean())

    category_risk = final_df.groupby('Category')['SuspiciousFlag'].mean()
    final_df['CategoryRisk'] = final_df['Category'].map(category_risk)

    # customer_frequency = final_df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'Dates'])['TransactionID'].count().reset_index()
    threshold = final_df['TransactionAmount'].quantile(0.95)

    final_df['LargeTransactionFlag'] = (final_df['TransactionAmount'] > threshold).astype(int)

    final_df['RollingAverage'] = final_df.groupby('CustomerID')['TransactionAmount'].transform(
    lambda x: x.rolling(window=5, min_periods=1).mean()
)

    final_df['SpendingAnomaly'] = (final_df['TransactionAmount'] > 1.5 * final_df['RollingAverage']).astype(int)

    final_df['SuspiciousActivityFlag'] = (
    (final_df['TransactionAmount'] > final_df['TransactionAmount'].quantile(0.95)) |
    (final_df['AnomalyScore'] > 0.8) |
    final_df['LargeTransactionFlag'] |
    final_df['SpendingAnomaly']
).astype(int)

    final_df['TransactionAmountToBalanceRatio'] = final_df['TransactionAmount'] / final_df['AccountBalance']
    final_df['HighRatioFlag'] = (final_df['TransactionAmountToBalanceRatio'] > 1).astype(int)

    final_df['CombinedRiskScore'] = (
    final_df['SuspiciousActivityFlag']
)
    final_df['FinalFraudFlag'] = (final_df['CombinedRiskScore'] > 1).astype(int)

    final_df.columns = [col.replace('TransactionID_x', 'TransactionID') for col in final_df.columns]
    final_df.drop(columns=['MerchantName', 'Category', 'Location', 'Name', 'Address', 'Timestamp', 'LastLogin', 'Dates'], inplace=True)

    scale_features = ['TransactionAmount','AccountBalance',
    'TransactionAmountToBalanceRatio',
    'SpendingTrend',
    'RollingAverage',
    'AvgTransactionAmount_Customer',
    'AvgTransactionAmount_Merchant']

    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    final_df[scale_features] = scaler.fit_transform(final_df[scale_features])

    # print(final_df[scale_features].head())
    # print(final_df.columns)
    # print(final_df.dtypes)

    X = final_df.drop(columns=['FinalFraudFlag'])
    y = final_df['FinalFraudFlag']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions
    y_pred = rf_model.predict(X_test)

    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")
    print("\nClassification Report:")
    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

# Confusion Matrix
    print("\nConfusion Matrix:")
    print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))


# Evaluate the model
    print("ROC AUC Score:", roc_auc_score(y_test, rf_model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]))


Welcome to SO. Please focus your question on a single issue, which should be about programming (i.e. here the programming error), and not about ML theory or methodology (i.e. why you get 100% accuracy); the latter is off-topic here, please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info for more

Additionally, I am afraid your code indentation is a mess; please post a proper [mre]
